# Where exactly is the limited broadcast address used?

Tags: router, ip, ip-address, layer3, broadcast

I read that limited broadcast address will be dropped by the router. So, it's not used in the layer-3 (Network layer), where IP addresses are meant to be used. So, where exactly is it used?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any broadcasts are limited to a layer-2 domain, which is bounded by a layer-3 device (router).

An application designer, needing to send broadcasts on any subnet where the application may be run, could use the Limited Broadcast address as a hard-coded address rather than spending the time to figure out the subnet broadcast address for the subnet on which the application finds itself.

Comment: So, consider this scenario. There is router R connected to switches A,B,C. Each switch is connected to 5 systems. If a system in switch A sends a limited broadcast, will it be broadcasted only to the systems under switch A, or to all the systems under switches A,B,C?

Comment: It depends on how many switches are in the same layer-2 domain. A broadcast (Limited Broadcast or subnet broadcast) will not be routed to another subnet, but if the switches are bridged to each other at layer-2, the broadcast will cross the bridge. Multicasts are treated the same way unless multicast routing is enabled on the routers between the layer-2 domains..